# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Path cannot be null

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I got this error when I am trying to add a data to the database when the image in the picture box is empty, but when the picturebox contains a image, the system working well.

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Path cannot be null.

The error is pointed on:

> fsStream = new FileStream(this.imagePath, FileMode.Open,
>   FileAccess.Read);

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Random _random = new Random();
        Timer _timer = new Timer();
        Wait _wait = new Wait();

        FileStream fsStream;
        BinaryReader bReader;

        byte[] imageByte = null;

        string imagePath;

        string gender;

        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                dlg.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName.ToString());
                    imagePath = dlg.FileName;
                }
            }
        }


public virtual void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fsStream = new FileStream(this.imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            bReader = new BinaryReader(fsStream);
            imageByte = bReader.ReadBytes((int)fsStream.Length);

            if (this.pictureBox1.Image == null || this.textBox2.Text == "" || this.textBox3.Text == "" || this.textBox4.Text == "" || this.textBox5.Text == "")
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Cannot Submit!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else if (this.label9.Visible == false)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You have to check the Student ID before proceeding!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else if (this.label8.Visible == true)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You cannot use this Student ID. Please Get another Student ID instead!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else if (this.label7.Visible == true)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Student ID is being verified! Please wait!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO [Student] ([StudentID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Photo], [DateOfBirth], [Address], [JoinedDate], [Class], [Gender]) VALUES (@StudentID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Photo, @DateOfBirth, @Address, @JoinedDate, @Class, @Gender)";

                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@StudentID"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = this.textBox2.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = this.textBox3.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarBinary);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Photo"].Value = imageByte;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@DateOfBirth"].Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Address"].Value = this.textBox4.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@JoinedDate", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@JoinedDate"].Value = this.dateTimePicker2.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Class", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Class"].Value = this.textBox5.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Gender"].Value = gender;

                        _wait.ShowDialog();

                        System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                        _sound.Play();

                        DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the image:

[image]

> **button1_Click is for Upload a Photo (The image will be shown in top**
>   ***right corner)***
>
> **button2_Click is for Submit (Adding data to the database)**

Anyone can help me?

Your answer much appreciated!

Comment: What line does the exception get thrown on?  Presumably you are calling a method on that line and you're passing `null` to one of its parameters.  Either make sure that the argument is not `null` or don't call the method if it is.

Comment: Sir Raphael Altahus already have the answer. Thank you @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess (maybe wrong) that the error happens on this line :

```
fsStream = new FileStream(this.imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

So you should add a null check

```
if (this.imagePath != null)
```

before this line, and correct the following code.

As you can see in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this ctor of FileStream will raise an `ArgumentNullException` if path is null.